# PySpark DataFrame writing empty (zero bytes) files

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working with `PySpark` `DataFrame` API with Spark version 3.1.1 on a local setup. After reading in data, performing some transformations etc. I save the `DataFrame` to disk. Output directories get created, along with `part-0000*` file and there is `_SUCCESS` file present in the output directory as well. However, my `part-0000*` is always empty i.e. zero bytes.

I've tried writing it in both `parquet` as well as `csv` formats with the same result. Just before writing, I called `df.show()` to make sure there is data in the `DataFrame`.

```
### code.py ###
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import configs

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('My Spark App').getOrCreate()
data = spark.read.csv(configs.dataset_path, sep=configs.data_delim)

rdd = data.rdd.map(...)
data = spark.createDataFrame(rdd)
data = data.withColumn('col1', F.lit(1))

data.show()  # Shows top 20 rows with data

data.write.parquet(save_path + '/dataset_parquet/', mode='overwrite') # Zero Bytes
data.write.csv(save_path + '/dataset_csv/', mode='overwrite')         # Zero Bytes
```

I'm running this code as follows

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
    --master local[*] \
    code.py
```

Comment: what happens if you try to write RDD to disk?

Comment: Just tested with `rdd`, same result.

Answer (score 0):

So I ran into a similar issue with pyspark and one thing I also noticed is that when I tried to set the mode to overwrite it was also failing. The issue with the overwrite was that it was failing to write while it was in the middle of the write, so it would create the file, fail, retry and the retry would fail with the 'file already exists' because it was past the point in its process of handling the overwrite.

So I added cache to force the evaluation because like your .show() above I was doing a data.cache().count(). The count showed records but any further evaluation using show or write showed the DF as empty.

So try adding .cache() to the first reference of that dataframe and see it it fixes your issue. It did for me.

```
df_bad = df_cln.filter(F.col('isInvalid')).select(F.concat(F.col('line')\
                       ,F.lit(">> LINE:"),F.col('monotonically_increasing_id'))\
                       .alias("line"),F.col('monotonically_increasing_id'))
removed_file_cnt = df_bad.cache().count()
    print(f"The count of the records still containing udf chars in the file: {removed_file_cnt}")
if removed_file_cnt > 0:
            df_bad.coalesce(1)\
            .orderBy('monotonically_increasing_id')\
            .drop('monotonically_increasing_id')\
            .write.option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace","false").option("encoding", "UTF-8")\
            .format('text').save(s3_error_bucket_path, mode='overwrite')
```

Alternatively, consider using a .localCheckpoint() on the data column. It is fast and convenient. Since we can always restart the job there essentially no critical need for a checkpoint.